# pydrive: RedirectMissingLocation: Redirected but the response is missing a Location: header

Tags: google-drive-api, pydrive

I need to override an existing file inside a google drive folder with a new file. This is what I have.

```
file = drive.CreateFile({'id': <id_of_file_which_I_wish_to_overwrite>})
file.SetContentFile(<my_file_path>)
file.Upload()
print('title: %s, mimeType: %s' % (file5['title'], file5['mimeType']))
```

I keep getting an error from file.Upload() line such as this:

```
RedirectMissingLocation: Redirected but the response is missing a Location: header.
```

Any ideas of what's causing this? What this Location is or the header? I noticed that I am not getting this error when I run the same code without file.SetContentFile and instead only change file metadata instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Hello @user10467920, which libraries are you using for your project? Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ale13 , I'm using the following:

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
and 
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

My authentication seems to work fine because I've used the setup before on other projects. It's only when I run the f.Upload() method that I get the error.

Comment: So it seems like the problem was the size of the file I was trying to upload on google drive. Running the exact same thing as the code I gave above worked for a much much smaller subset of that same data on the file. My original file was huge (a few million records) so it was throwing the RedirectMissingLocation error. I find that the error message wasn't really informative/descriptive of what was actually happening. In any case, my problem is solve now.

Answer (score 16):

You know, PyDrive is a wrapper library of google-api-python-client.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/803), there is some problem between google-api-python-client and httplib2.

So try installing a 0.15.0 version of httplib2.
`pip install httplib2==0.15.0`

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at the **size of the file** that is being uploaded on Google Drive since you are getting the `RedirectMissingLocation` error.

Running the code above works for a much much smaller subset of that same data on the file.

Comment: You're right, I tested with a smaller file and I could send it to GCP.

Comment: So with big file, what should we do?